vs code issue flutter project
vs code issue not detect any error not wrap any widget not show widget suggestion when click ctrl + . in flutter project , please help me how fo fix
i try many thing but not fix please any one help how to fix , because without sugestino and error detaction coding is impossible not import any page

do you see any dart language-server process running on your PC?

sorry what you say i don't understand , please help how to fix this issue

on windows, type Ctrl + Shift + Esc to see your processes and check if dart language-server is running

i am using mac book

so you have ps command i believe

Did you create a file but didn't add the Dart extension? Usually, this problem occurs when we forget to add the extension. pls check it

new_file.dart

